# iPhone looses png transparency for photos synced with iPhoto

Tags: iphone, ios, png, transparency, iphoto

I am making an iphone app that needs the user to give it images with transparency. I was expecting that I could user iPhoto to sync my photos to the iPhone then use the image picker to import the photos into my app. However when I do this I loose the transparency. I know I could allow the user to import photos using iTunes and the documents folder but I would rather use iPhoto and the built in image picker. Is there anyway to make this work. If not is there documentation that explains this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess - When you are getting the image are you using UIImagePNGRepresentation? If not you might be getting a jpeg instead, as I think that it is the default. Maybe post dome code on how you are getting the image, after it is chosen from the picker.

Jonathan